# Web Crawler error: "AttributeError: Spider instance has no attribute 'find'"

Tags: python, web-crawler, urlparse

I'm having an issue with my web crawler and the urlparse plugin for python. My code below basically crawls a specific domain such as bloomberg and downloads all the html to my desktop. It's still in quite early stage so I'm sure you will notice errors etc (I'm new to python.)

The specific issue I'm having at the moment is relating to the function `reconstruct_url`. I've tested the `urlparse.urljoin(a,b)` function individually and it operates in the way I would expect, but in this class it just doesn't like it. Could any of you help show me what the issue is here?

If any other issues are blindingly obvious to you in my code please feel free to shout them out as well, this is my first attempt at writing a full program. Although note this is still in relatively early stages. Thanks a lot for any help.

```
#note: <meta content='Story' property='bb:resource_type'>

import urllib2
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin

class Spider:

    links_to_crawl = []
    crawled_links = []
    ignored_links = ['/']
    domain = 'http://bloomberg.com/'
    #meta type = ('meta', {'property','bb:resource_type'})['content']=='Story'

    # append all starting link to links_to_crawl
    def __init__(self, url):
        print 'Spider initialising...'
        self.links_to_crawl.append(url)

    # open input url and return html
    def grab_html(self,url):
        open_url = self.urllib2.urlopen(url)
        data = open_url.read()
        open_url.close()
        return data

    # return title from input html for file naming and ensure
    # no '/' present in title.
    def get_title(self, data=''):
        title_start = data.find('<title>')+7
        title_end = data.find('</title>')-1
        title = data[title_start:title_end]
        title = title.translate(None, '/')
        return title+".txt"

    # return date from input html for file saving structure
    def get_date(self, data=''):
        soup = self.BeautifulSoup(data)
        # try statement to avoid error when meta tag combinations
        # not found.
        try:
            date = soup.find('meta', {'name':'pubdate'})['content']
            return date[:12] # !! only tested with bloomberg.com !!
        # if there is no published date, return 'Other'
        except TypeError:
            return 'Other'

    # if link is relative url return 'Rel' or 
    # if url is allowed domain return 'Abs', else False.
    def url_type(self,url=''):
        if url[0:4] != 'http':
            return 'Rel'
        elif url.find(self.domain) != -1:
            return 'Abs'
        else:
            return False

    # reconstruct relative url
    def reconstruct_url(self, page='', rel=''):
        print page #debug
        print rel #debug
        print self.urljoin(page, rel) #debug
        return self.urljoin(page, rel)

    # get all links in input html and append to links_to_crawl
    # unless in crawled_links or ignored_links
    # if link is relative url reconstruct url and append to 
    # links_to_crawl, append relative url to ignored_links
    def get_links(self, data=''):
        soup = self.BeautifulSoup(data) 
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            # try statement to avoid error when finding
            # <a> tags withou 'href'
            try:
                if link['href'] in self.ignored_links or self.crawled_links:
                    pass
                else:
                    if self.url_type(link['href'])=='Rel':
                        reconstructed_link = self.reconstruct_url(self.domain, link['href']) #to change !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                        self.links_to_crawl.append(reconstructed_link) # append reconstructed link to links_to_crawl
                        self.ignored_links.append(link['href']) # append original link to ignored_links
                    else:
                        self.links_to_crawl.append(link['href'])
            except KeyError:
                pass

    # if directory exists do nothing
    # if directory does not exist write directory
    def ensure_dir(self, directory=''):
        if self.os.path.exists(directory):
            pass
        else:
            self.os.makedirs(directory)

    # ensure the html being saved is the type requested
    # currently only compatible with 1 meta type
    def ensure_meta_type(self, data=''):
        soup = self.BeautifulSoup(data)
        try:
            soup.find('meta', {'property':'bb:resource_type'})['content']=='Story'
            print 'True'
            return True
        except TypeError:
            print 'False'
            return False

    # save input html to txt file on mac os desktop and return
    # absolute path to file
    def save_html(self,data=''):
        if self.ensure_meta_type(data):
            print 'SAVING URL'
            # allocate save path for file and ensure save path exists
            save_path = self.os.path.abspath('/Users/sampeka/Desktop/Python Spider'+'/'+self.get_date(data))
            self.ensure_dir(save_path)
            # get file name and write file to absolute path
            file_name = self.get_title(data)
            absolute_path = save_path+'/'+file_name
            opened_file = open(absolute_path,'w')
            opened_file.write(data)
            opened_file.close()
        else:
            pass



    # crawl links_to_crawl and pop to crawled_links list
    # if ValueError then pop to ignored_links
    # except urllib2.URLError to avoid web crawler crawling
    # non-url links  
    def crawl_links(self):
        while len(self.links_to_crawl) > 0:
            url = self.links_to_crawl[0]
            print url
            try:
                data = self.grab_html(url)
                self.get_links(data)
                self.save_html(data)
                self.crawled_links.append(self.links_to_crawl.pop(0))
            except (ValueError, self.urllib2.URLError):
                self.ignored_links.append(self.links_to_crawl.pop(0))
        print 'Spider finished.'
        print 'Ignored links:'
        print self.ignored_links
        print 'Crawled links:'
        print self.crawled_links


spider = Spider('http://www.bloomberg.com/news')
spider.crawl_links()
```

Comment: Brushed your code a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @twil mentioned, Also you are using `self` for some other modules, [here](http://www.diffchecker.com/hglpoon7) is a diff of your code and corrected code for all of them.

Comment: I would have up voted both but don't have enough reputation to unfortunately.

Comment: @SamP, Sorry, unfortunately I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `reconstruct_url()` doesn't work because you are trying to use undefined method `self.urljoin` of `Spider`. Just use the function you've imported from `urlparse`:

```
# reconstruct relative url
def reconstruct_url(self, page='', rel=''):
    print page #debug
    print rel #debug
    print urljoin(page, rel) #debug
    return urljoin(page, rel)
```